# No adapter attached for RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I'am trying to retrieve product images and their relevant details from a server url using recycler-view and card-view. However, i'am getting an error stating: "No adapter attached; skipping layout".
Could anyone please help me sort it out by looking through the code.

Mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
List<GetDataAdapter> GetDataAdapter1;
RecyclerView recyclerview;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerViewlayoutManager;
RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewadapter;

String GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL="http://staging.giftintime.com/mobile/categories/3/subcategories";
String JSON_IMAGE_TITLE_NAME="name";
String JSON_IMAGE_URL = "master_variant_images";
String JSON_IMAGE_PRICE="price";
String JSON_IMAGE_DESC="description";

JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest;
RequestQueue requestQueue;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_him);

    GetDataAdapter1 = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerview = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);
    recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerview.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewlayoutManager);

    JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL();
}
public void JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL(){

    jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}
public void JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(JSONArray array){
    for (int i =0;i<array.length();i++) {
        GetDataAdapter GetDataAdapter2 = new GetDataAdapter();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);
            GetDataAdapter2.setImageTitleName(json.getString(JSON_IMAGE_TITLE_NAME));
            GetDataAdapter2.setImageServerURL(json.getString(JSON_IMAGE_URL));
            GetDataAdapter2.setImagePrice(json.getString(JSON_IMAGE_PRICE));
            GetDataAdapter2.setImageDesc(json.getString(JSON_IMAGE_DESC));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        GetDataAdapter1.add(GetDataAdapter2);
    }
        recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(GetDataAdapter1, this) ;
        recyclerview.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
        }

    }
```

Here is the RECYCLERVIEW ADAPTER:

```
 public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;
List<GetDataAdapter>getDataAdapter;
ImageLoader imageLoader1;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<GetDataAdapter>getDataAdapter,Context context){
    super();
    this.getDataAdapter = getDataAdapter;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_items,parent,false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder= new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    GetDataAdapter getDataAdapter1 = getDataAdapter.get(position);
    imageLoader1 = ServerImageParseAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
    imageLoader1.get(getDataAdapter1.getImageServerURL(),
            ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                    holder.networkImageView,
                    R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
                    android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert
            )
    );
    holder.networkImageView.setImageUrl(getDataAdapter1.getImageServerURL(), imageLoader1);
    holder.ImageTitleNameView.setText(getDataAdapter1.getImageTitleName());
    holder.ImagePriceView.setText(getDataAdapter1.getImagePrice());
    holder.ImageDescView.setText(getDataAdapter1.getImageDesc());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return getDataAdapter.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView ImageTitleNameView;
    public NetworkImageView networkImageView ;
    public TextView ImagePriceView;
    public TextView ImageDescView ;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ImageTitleNameView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_itemname);
        networkImageView = (NetworkImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.VolleyNetworkImageView1);
        ImagePriceView = (TextView )itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_itemprice);
        ImageDescView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_itemdesc);


    }
}
}
```

SERVERIMAGEPARSEADAPTER.JAVA

```
public class ServerImageParseAdapter {
public static ServerImageParseAdapter SIAdapter;
public static Context context1;
public RequestQueue requestQueue1;
public ImageLoader Imageloader1;
public Cache cache1 ;
public Network networkOBJ ;
LruCache<String, Bitmap> LRUCACHE = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(30);

private ServerImageParseAdapter(Context context) {

    this.context1 = context;
    this.requestQueue1 = RQ();

    Imageloader1 = new ImageLoader(requestQueue1, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {

        @Override
        public Bitmap getBitmap(String URL) {
            return LRUCACHE.get(URL);
        }

        @Override
        public void putBitmap(String URL, Bitmap bitmap) {
            LRUCACHE.put(URL, bitmap);
        }

});
    }
public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    return Imageloader1;
}
public static ServerImageParseAdapter getInstance(Context SynchronizedContext) {

    if (SIAdapter == null) {
        SIAdapter = new ServerImageParseAdapter(SynchronizedContext);
    }
    return SIAdapter;
}
private RequestQueue RQ() {
    if (requestQueue1 == null) {

        cache1 = new DiskBasedCache(context1.getCacheDir());

        networkOBJ = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());

        requestQueue1 = new RequestQueue(cache1, networkOBJ);

        requestQueue1.start();
    }
    return requestQueue1;
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [recyclerview No adapter attached; skipping layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141729/recyclerview-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout)

Comment: did u debug your code?

Comment: @quicklearner: yeah, actually json data is getting displayed when i run the code.

Comment: I guess something has to be included within onResponse call , since i am new to android coding i don't know what exactly has to be included. If someone can suggest it will be a greater help.

Answer (score 0):

Just set an empty adapter first, update it as soon as you have the data

```
recyclerview = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);
recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerViewlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
recyclerview.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewlayoutManager);
recyclerview.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
```

this work for me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141729/recyclerview-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout?noredirect=1&lq=1